# Parse PowerShell output in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, powershell, output

How can parse the output of powerShell console in C#?

PowerShell console output:

```
Name        : 0F06B9DF-9FC5-4AF7-AF92-890AAD415000
ElementName : Virtual Machine 1

Name        : 2B501DD8-46F5-45FE-ACCE-62030720A000
ElementName : Virtual Machine 2
```

In my C# code read the output line by line. I search the best way to convert the output to the

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>>
```

I tried

```
bool dataset = false;
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    // The line of Output
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

    // If line is not empty save data in dictionary
    if(line.Length != 0)
    {
        dataset = true;
        string[] vals = line.Split(':');
        data.Add(vals[0], vals[1]);
    }
    // Else, save dictionary in list and reinit dictionary
    else
    {
        // Next object
        if (dataset)
        { 
            arr.Add(data);
            dataset = false;
            data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to show the command you're using to generate that output.

Comment: Why do you want a list of dictionaries, when it would be sufficient to just have a dictionary of strings?

Comment: How can i use a dictionary of strings in my case? PS: I added the code that i use.

Comment: What is the problem you've observed with the approach you're taking? In what way does it not work?

Comment: It working but I search the optimal way to do this task.

Comment: The question is quite old, so I don't know if the problem still exists, but you could use [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) to give out a string that can be far easier parsed then the default powershell output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process finishes quickly and doesn't provide a lot of output, then it might be a good idea to wait for it to exit, and then read all of the standard output stream at once.

```
proc.WaitForExit((int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);

var ret = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

// first split on double newline to separate VMs
string[] vms = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    .Split(new[] { string.Format("{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine) }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var vm in vms)
{
    // then split on newline, to get each line in separate string
    var lines = vm.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // finally, split each line on ':' to fill in dictionary, then add it to list
    ret.Add(lines.Select(line => line.Split(':')).ToDictionary(a => a[0].Trim(), a => a[1].Trim()));
}
```

You'll probably also want to wrap it in `try...catch` in case the process output is not in the format you expect.

Comment: I don't need a loop to adding the dictionary in list? I receive the error: An Item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should now work for you, and output `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` with each VM being a separate `Dictionary<string,string>`. It is kind of ugly solution though - I recommend taking the path @n0rd suggested, and get Powershell output as an object if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Come on! C# and Powershell - both .Net languages. You can invoke Powershell scripts form C# and get output as objects. No need to parse anything:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rsc = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsc);
        runSpace.Open();
        Runspace.DefaultRunspace = runSpace;
        var p = runSpace.CreatePipeline("Get-Process");

        var output = p.Invoke();

        foreach (var o in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.Properties["Name"].Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can not do this. I forgot to say that run on server 2008 PowerShell v2.0. I don't have system.management.automation. I using this library : http://pshyperv.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
              {
                  // this script has a sleep in it to simulate a long running script
                  PowerShellInstance.AddScript("GET-VM");
                  //PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Out-String");
                  // begin invoke execution on the pipeline

                  foreach (var o in PowerShellInstance.Invoke())
                  {
                      //Console.WriteLine(str);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.Properties["Name"].Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.Properties["Status"].Value);
                }
                  // do something else until execution has completed.
                  // this could be sleep/wait, or perhaps some other work

}
```